# Exporting Derby Database netbeans 8.1 with web application project

Tags: java, database, rest, netbeans, derby

I used netbeans' automatic generation of entity classes from database and automatic generation of JSF pages from entity classes to build a simple CRUD web application.

I used glassfish server and java db.

Now I want to move the application to be usable on a usb stick for submission for a one time use.

How could i export/move the project with the data and configuration settings in place so the database will work with the project on another computer?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Make a backup of the database using Derby's backup tools, or simply shut down the database and then copy the folder. If you are using the Derby Network Server in your app (i.e, you are using the client-server configuration), then either switch to embedded or start the server on the new machine. Use IJ to test your database access on the new machine.

Comment: Hi, the main issue i am having is that, i have created a web application in netbeans, in which i am connecting to the derby database and i am using restful webservice to allow user to enter new data as shown in this video link below. However, when i try to run my project after shutting netbeans, it no longer works in the same way. The project produces .xhtml file which no longer works once netbeans is closed. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Aec0KEDdzE                                I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Can you provide substantially more details than "it no longer works in the same way" and "no longer works once netbeans is closed"? As in, do you get an exception? What are the details of the exception? I suspect that Netbeans is running a Derby Network Server for you, and so if you shut it down you have to start your own Derby Network Server, but really I'm just guessing because you need to give us more information.

Comment: Your assumption is correct, ive concluded that when i close netbeans, the glassfish server disconnects and any other connections, hence the application no longer runs. I am currently looking at hosing remotely via glassfish to establish a connection or to host via amazon web service for deployment.